# Adding a group of annotations from one pdf in all pages of another pdf and create a new output pdf

Tags: c#, itext7

I have created a reader for Input file and one for the Markup file. I am not sure if I should loop through the annotations and then add them one by one to the output or if there is a way to pull all the annotations from the markup file and add them to the input file retaining their x,z coordinates.

I have the below code, and I am not sure what to do at the commented section. The AddAnnotation method only takes PdfAnnotation as input but I am not sure how to convert the PdfDictionary to PdfAnnotaiton.

```
class Program
{
    public static string inputFile = @"E:\pdf-sample.pdf";
    public static string markupFile = @"E:\StampPdf.pdf";
    public static string outputFile = @"E:\pdf.pdf";

    public static PdfReader inputReader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
    public static PdfReader markupReader = new PdfReader(markupFile);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfDocument inputDoc = new PdfDocument(inputReader, new PdfWriter(outputFile));

        PdfDocument markupDoc = new PdfDocument(markupReader);

        int n = inputDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            PdfPage page = inputDoc.GetPage(i);

            PdfDictionary markupPage = markupDoc.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject();
            PdfArray annots = markupPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annots);

            if(annots != null)
            {
                for(int j=0; j < annots.Size(); j++)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annotItem = annots.GetAsDictionary(i);
                    //******
                    //page.AddAnnotation(?);
                    //******
                }
            }
        }
        inputDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

I tried another variation after I found new GetAnnotations method in iText7. Here the code runs fine but I am not able to open the O/P file and get an error that the file is corrupted. Also when I ran inputDoc.Close() instead of the last line given below, I got an error “Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.”

```
        PdfReader ireader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        PdfDocument inputDoc = new PdfDocument(ireader, new PdfWriter(outputFile));
        PdfReader mreader = new PdfReader(markupFile);
        PdfDocument markupDoc = new PdfDocument(mreader);
        var annots = markupDoc.GetFirstPage().GetAnnotations();
        if (annots != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < annots.Count(); j++)
            {
                inputDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(annots[j]);
            }
        }
        ireader.Close();
        mreader.Close();
        markupDoc.Close();
        inputDoc.SetCloseWriter(true);
```

Comment: What library are you using for reading pdf's ?

Comment: @Piotr - I'm using iText7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this :

```
    if (annots != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size(); j++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotItem = annots.GetAsDictionary(i);
            PdfLineAnnotation lineAnnotation = new PdfLineAnnotation(annotItem);
            page.AddAnnotation(lineAnnotation);
        }
    }
```

If it doesn't work, here is some documentation (unfortunately in Java)

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/clone-creating-and-adding-annotations

If you could post Pdf with annotations you wish to copy - maybe I can debug and try something more.

Comment: @Piotr-I have added images of my input and markup pdf files you can refer it and as you can see it contains many line of annotations.Can u help me with some suggestions. Or can u send me the your mail id soi can mail u the pdf's.

Comment: Upload it and give us a link (for example: https://wetransfer.com/) - this way not only me but everyone would have a chance to help you with that)

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fb37905d3501892ff4808e487452928220170804122229/97c1b7

Comment: I have added the link for input pdf and the pdf containing the markup.